# How should I separate following three string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, split

```
String s0 = "uc=3 t=450 lb=hh";
String s1 = "uc=3 t=450 lb=tp";
String s2 = "uc=3 t=450 lb=vs";

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    String[] s4 = si.split(" ");
}
```

how should I use "i" th value of s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply No.

You cannot create a `variable` name dynamically.

When you do `si`  it behaves like a `string` and not the original variable.

What you can do is prepare an `array` and iterate over them.

```
       String[] array = {s0,s1,s2};

        for (String string : array) {
            String[] resultArray = string.split(" ");
        }
```

Comment: Technically if they are fields you can do it like the OP asks with reflection. I would never recommend that though. : P

Comment: @Radiodef Yes. True.If fields you can do it with reflection.  But no, If local variables :)

Comment: Thanks for replying and helping you both.Why don't you recommend?

Comment: @user2935408 One thing first I can say Is , go for reflection when you don't have any other possibilty to do your  task, more over it is very slow. Please have a look at this link since I cannot explain every reason https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/SEC05-J.+Do+not+use+reflection+to+increase+accessibility+of+classes,+methods,+or+fields

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to save the strings `s1` `s2` and `s3` in an array of strings.

```
String[] si = { "uc=3 t=450 lb=hh",
    "uc=3 t=450 lb=tp",
    "uc=3 t=450 lb=vs" };
```

then you can loop over it

```
for(String s : si) { // enhanced for loop
    String s4[] = s.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, because it doesn't mess around with the entirely pointless `s0`, `s1` and `s2`.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array:

```
String[] s = new String[]{s0, s1, s2};
```

Then you can use `s[i]` to get `i-th` element of s.

or create a list:

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList(s0, s1, s2);
```

and use `s.get(i)` to get `i-th` element of s.

Answer (score 2):

Make an array of String `sArr`, than iterate over this array and split.

```
String sArr[]={s0,s1,s2};
for(String s:sArr){
   String[] s4=s.split(" ");
}
```